# Runtime error: Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: The keyword 'interface' is reserved

Tags: next.js

I am using `next-compose-plugins` and when I try to build nextjs app, it throws error:

> Runtime error: Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: The keyword 'interface' is reserved.
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.

```
const nextConfig = {
  distDir: "../../build",
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '*',
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'x-custom-header',
            value: 'my custom header value',
          },
          {
            key: 'x-another-custom-header',
            value: 'my other custom header value',
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
}
module.exports = withPlugins(
  [withCSS], [withSaas], [withImages], [nextSourceMaps], [withTM],
{
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    config.optimization.minimizer = [];
    config.optimization.minimizer.push(new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({}));
    if (!isServer) {
      config.resolve.alias["@sentry/node"] = "@Sentry (Legacy)/browser";
    }
    return config;
  },
}, nextConfig);
```

I am using `react-jss` and I think this is what I am missing configuration for. I am not sure what's wrong in my configuration. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Smells like loading some TypeScript within your JS, it works if you remove the withPlugins?